# Setting div height to englobing div height

Tags: css, height, html

I have a div containing two aligned `div`s. Unfortunately, the right `div` does not have the proper height as visible from its backgroung color. How can I make sure it will ajust its height to that of the englobing `div`?

The Html:

```
<div id="engl">
    <div id="lleft">Some text text
     text  text  text  text  text  text
     text  text  text  text  text  text
    </div>
    <div id="rright">Other text</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#engl {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

#lleft {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 140px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#rright {
    background-color: green;
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
    height: inherited;
}
```

The JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bLLN/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use positioning to do this:

```
#engl {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position:relative; /*NEW*/
}
#lleft {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 140px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
#rright {
    background-color: green;
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
    height: inherited;
    position: absolute; /*NEW*/
    top:0; /*NEW*/
    bottom:0; /*NEW*/
    right:0; /*NEW*/
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9bLLN/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

The modified html:

```
<div id="engl">
    <div id="lleft">Some text text
     text  text  text  text  text  text
     text  text  text  text  text  text
    </div>
    <div id="rright">Other text</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

The modified css:

```
#rright {
    background-color: green;
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Floating elements can't say their height to their parent. This is because a third, empty DIV with a "clear: both" is also required.

This solution is a little bit  problematic, because from the browsers viewpoint it isn't  trivial, the height of which element should specify which. But with current browsers (ie8+) works.